Understanding には in this sentence
From 若き時代の道:

いかに生きるべきかが考え直されている根底には、生きることがないがどうしよう、というばかりではなく、人間的な理性と感情とから否定されるべき事物は分っている。

I am lost on how to parse this sentence. In particular, I am not sure what is the role of には after 根底. Is it linked to 生きることがない or 分っている.

I was equally lost at first, but there seem to be two implicit quotes. And the second quote is very long, spanning multiple sentences. It can be parsed like this:

いかに生きるべきかが考え直されている根底には、「生きることがないがどうしよう」というばかりではなく、[「]{L}人間的な理性と感情とから否定されるべき事物は分っている。だが、それをどういう実際のやりかたで表現して行くべきか、どこにその道があるか。知識人として肯定し建設すべきもののきっかけを矛盾だらけの社会関係にある自分の日常生活でどう掴み、どうものにしてゆくべきか[」]{L}という熱心な苦しい摸索があるのである。
Beneath the reconsideration of how one ought to live, there are not only concerns like "生きることがないがどうしよう", but there also lies a serious and difficult exploration like "人間的な理性と感情と～どうものにしてゆくべきか".

So this 根底には is linked to 模索がある several periods later.
The author seems to have thoroughly eliminated brackets in this essay. Quotation marks were rarely used until the Edo period, so the author, as an "intelligentsia", might have wanted to give the traditional and authoritative air to her text by not using brackets. In modern literary works, it is quite rare to see such a bold omission of brackets for multi-sentence quotations.
